# Python 3 imaplib.fetch TypeError: can't concat bytes to int

Tags: python, imap

I have some code which fetches IMAP emails and works completely well in Python 2. In Python3  I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "./mail.py", line 295, in 
>           item=return_message(x)
>         File "./mail.py", line 122, in return_message
>           result, data = mail.fetch(message_id, "(RFC822)")
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/imaplib.py", line 460, in fetch
>           typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, message_set, message_parts)
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/imaplib.py", line 1113, in _simple_command
>           return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
>         File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/imaplib.py", line 883, in _command
>           data = data + b' ' + arg
>       TypeError: can't concat bytes to int

The code from the return_message function:

```
result, data = mail.fetch(message_id, "(RFC822)")
raw_email = data[0][1]
email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
```

Runtime Information:

> 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 01:25:11) 
>       [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]

Comment: Yes. message id comes via x = (int(len(id_list)) - int(indexCounter))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`message_set` is a string, not an int. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html):

> The `message_set` options to commands below is a string specifying one or more messages to be acted upon. It may be a simple message number (`'1'`), a range of message numbers (`'2:4'`), or a group of non-contiguous ranges separated by commas (`'1:3,6:9'`). A range can contain an asterisk to indicate an infinite upper bound (`'3:*'`).

Converting it to string directly should be enough:

```
result, data = mail.fetch(str(message_id), "(RFC822)")
```

Comment: This did it. I however now get another error, should I post that there or create a new question?

Comment: Let's make that a new post, it's a new problem after all.